# How can I convert SUTime objects into regular Calendar or Date objects?

Tags: java, stanford-nlp, sutime

When I use SUTime's API, I provide text and receive a list of `CoreMap` objects, each detailing the attributes of a time expression in the text. I wish to take such a `CoreMap` and convert it into a `Date` or `Calendar` object, for easier handling and manipulations.

Is there any such method in the SUTime API? Anywhere else for that matter?

Is there a reverse method for building a `CoreMap` out of a `Date` or `Calendar` object?

Answer (score 1):

To get a Calendar object out of a CoreMap cm extracted by SUTime, you can try:

Calendar calendar = cm.get(TimeAnnotations.TimexAnnotation.class).getDate();
(see https://github.com/stanfordnlp/CoreNLP/blob/master/src/edu/stanford/nlp/time/Timex.java)

Note that not all time expressions recognized by SUTime will resolve to a point in time or a Calendar object (so there maybe some exceptions).